# How to convert a string to float in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

How can we achieve an "in-place" conversion to float of values of a hash? The motivation is not having to write bunch of code like this

```
r['delivery_fee'] = r['delivery_fee'].to_f
r['delivery_free_over'] = r['delivery_free_over'].to_f
r['delivery_possible_over'] = r['delivery_possible_over'].to_f
r['delivery_range'] = r['delivery_range'].to_f
```

but rather

```
to_f r['delivery_fee']
to_f r['delivery_free_over']
# ...
```

I did this, but it does not work the way intended.

```
def to_f(s)
  s = s.to_f
end

data = "1"
p data # => "1"
to_f data
p data # => Still "1" and not float
```

Comment: You are getting confused. Your motivation was to change the values to a certain key in a hash. What you tried (and failed) is changing the referent of a certain variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by dbenhur, you need to change your hash, not the resulted string of a `hash[key]`.

```
h = {:key => 'value'}
def to_f(h, key)
  h[key] = h[key].to_f
end
to_f(h, :key)
# => 0.0
h
# => {:key=>0.0}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is easy:

```
h = { one: '1', two: '2' }

Hash[h.keys.zip(h.values.map(&:to_f))]
# => { :one => 1.0, :two => 2.0 }

# or

Hash[h.map {|k, v| [k, v.to_f] }]
# => { :one => 1.0, :two => 2.0 }
```

Which one of the two to use is a matter of preference, really.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you want because you can't change the object the variable references. You can only manipulate the object. You can't change a `String` object to a `Float`; you can only produce a new float derived from the string.

But you can make your code less repetitive:

```
%w{delivery_fee delivery_free_over delivery_possible_over delivery_range}.each do |k|
  r[k] = r[k].to_f
end
```